# arranging maps from greatest to least based on their stored values in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

Ok so I kindof have 2 questions but I think they're sortof easy to an experienced programmer and somewhat similar. If it bothers you, simply help me with 1 question & not the other. Basically I have a map(char, int) that associates the number of times a character appears in a string with an int value. The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to print out the associated values from most occuring to least occuring. For example, if i type aabbbcddddd. I get a:2 b:3 c:1 d:5.  But what I'm trying to get is d:5 b:3 a:2 c:1. I hope I'm explaining it okay...

Second question. I was also wondering how would one go about making a maps that does the *same* thing as above but with a **series** of letters OR numbers. Example: with string: 'aabbb001c1 ddd'... "aabbb", "c", and "ddd" would all be seperate words. "001" and "1" would be numbers, however they would **not** be equal. I tried using two seperate map(string, int) for this (one for words one for numbers), with a series cutting off when a character that's not of its "type" appeared, but nothings working. A technique or any advice would be nice. Here's the code I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string word;

    getline(cin, word);

    map<char,int> charCount;
    map<string, int> strCount;
    map<string, int> numCount;

    //turning all characters to lower case
    transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);

    //for loop to count recurring characters
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<word.size(); i++){
        charCount[word[i]]++;
    }

    //Having trouble here. This is where i'm doing my series of words & numbers
    string temp;
    string temp2;

    for (unsigned int j=0; j<word.size(); j++){
        if (isalpha(word[j]))
            temp = temp + word[j];
        else{
          wordCount[temp]++;
          temp2.clear();
        }
        if (isdigit(word[j]))
            temp2 = temp2 + word[j];
        else{
            numCount[temp2]++;
            temp2.clear();
        }

    }


    //print out chars
    for (map<char, int>::iterator it = charCount.begin(); it != charCount.end(); ++it)
        cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << endl;

    //print out words
    for (map<string, int>::iterator it = wordCount.begin(); it != wordCount.end(); ++it)
        cout << it->first << ": " << it->second <<endl;

    //print out numbers
    for (map<string, int>::iterator it = numCount.begin(); it != numCount.end(); ++it)
      cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `std::map` is sorted by it's key, not it's value, and neither the sorting mechanism nor the values of the keys can be changed after the map has been instantiated.

So your map is already sorted by `char`, but you want to display it the *value* -- a different sorting order.

The simplest thing to do would be to construct a `std::multimap` where the key is the number of occurrences (the value from the original map) and the value is the character.  Using a `multimap` as opposed to a `map` allows you to have multiple characters with the same number of occurrences.  When you're ready to display the values, copy the `map` keys and values to the `multimap` and then display the contents of the `multimap`.

Here's an example ([Live Demo](http://ideone.com/a907I1)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const string data = "foofaaster";

    // populate the map
    map <char, int> chars;
    for (auto c = data.begin(); c != data.end(); ++c)
        chars [*c]++;

    // Now display the occurances
    cout << "Original data: '" << data << "'" << endl;
    multimap <int, char, greater <int>> counts;
    for (auto c = chars.begin(); c != chars.end(); ++c)
        counts.insert (make_pair (c->second, c->first));
    cout << "Character counts:" << endl;
    for (auto it = counts.begin(); it != counts.end(); ++it)
        cout << "\t" << it->first << ": '" << it->second << "'" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

---

As for the second question, if your map's keys are static and there's one value per key, then you can use a `std::map <std::string, int>`.  Otherwise, if subelements of the key will have thier own values, you might consider another data structure more appropriate for the task, such as a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: That's helpful. But lol damn I was hoping the solution was going to be a bit easier than  that. I'm going to read into multimaps to fully understand 'em, thanks.